# how to export to csv file as it is shown in grid using mvc c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a grid with the following consist of file columns and header as its shown in the following :

```
   List<string> eventResult = (from c in DB.Events
                                    where (c.m_turbine_id == turbineid.turbineID) && (c.m_time_stamp >= frmDate && c.m_time_stamp <= toDate)

                                    select new EventLogPartialViewModel
                                    {
                                        Timestamp = c.m_time_stamp,
                                        Description = c.m_event_log_description,
                                        WindSpeed = c.m_wind_speed,
                                        RPM = c.m_rpm,
                                        Power = c.m_power
                                    }).ToList().Select(x =>
                  x.Timestamp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss") + "," +
                  x.Description + "," +
                  x.WindSpeed + "," +
                  x.RPM + "," +
                  x.Power)

             .ToList();
```

Im using the following conversion to get CSV file:

```
 string sss=string.Join(",",eventResult.ToArray());         
 byte[] csvBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sss);
```

here I export:

```
 return this.File(csvBytes, "text/csv",".csv");
```

when I open the file, headers are missing and all my data is in a single line,not like a grid

Comment: it is better use double quote for the data, if some data may have , in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already joined fields by comma in your last `select` statement, so final `Join` should be by new line.

```
string sss = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, eventResult.ToArray());
```

Typically I use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for generating csv files, since I don't want to validate or escape double quotation marks and commas in my input string. These are quite common characters that can disrupt the file.

For including a header full code is:

```
string header = "Timestamp,Description,WindSpeed,RPM,Power";
string rows = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, eventResult.ToArray());
byte[] csvBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header + Environment.NewLine + rows);
return File(csvBytes, "text/csv", ".csv");
```

Comment: its perfect! but how can I add also the name of my headers above,like timestamp,description,...?

Comment: if it's okay for the header to appear hardcoded as "col1, col2, col2, etc", it's just ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header + Environtment.NewLine + sss); But if you mean to update the header dynamically it can be done using System.Reflexion

Comment: like this?  string sss=string.Join("TimeStamp,Description+WindSpeed+RPM+Power"+Environment.NewLine,eventResult.ToArray());

Comment: but it does not give header

Comment: For standard csv file the header is just the first row. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Nice that you added the bit about escaping chars to avoid disruption.  +1 for that.  Also, as you know - a few things can corrupt a CSV file....Carriage returns or Line Feeds in a string, stray commas and quotes, null characters sneaking in, etc